# Without the throw exception deletes a key but with it doesn't?

Tags: java, hashtable

I am currently working on this method for my hash table and it currently looks as so.

```
  public void remove(String key) throws MapException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for(int i = 0; i <List.length;i++){
            if(List[i] !=null && List[i].equals(key)){
            List[i] = null;
            numberOfElements--;
        }else{
             throw new MapException("Nothing here", null);
        }
    }

}
```

My Question is when I remove the throw new MapException it works in deleting an actual entry from the hash table, but when it is there it throws the exception but doesn't delete an actual entry?

Comment: Step through your code. What happens if `i = 0`? Is the `if` true? I bet not.

Comment: Hint: work on the formatting of your code ... Alone the fact that your else "sits" too far on the left makes it harder to understand your code ...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect List[i] is alredy null and 'if' block is never executed. In that case:

- Keeping MapException the exception will be thrown
- Deleting MapException nothing will be executed in that iteration and List[i] will keep back the null value, which lead you to think 'if' block has been executed.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop throws on the first found entry which is null or whose key does not equal the given one. So if your desired key to delete is after that in the list, it never will be reached.

You should change the logic in the if statement for checking if it is NOT the searched key, in order to just continue with the next list entry. If you have found a key and deleted it then you have to remember it in order to throw AFTER the loop:

```
public void remove( String key ) throws Exception
{
    boolean deleted = false;
    for ( int i = 0; i < list.length; i++ )
    {
        if ( List[i] == null || !List[i].equals( key ) )
        {
            continue;
        }
        ist[i] = null;
        numberOfElements--;
        deleted = true;
    }

    if ( !deleted )
    {
        throw new Exception( "Nothing here" );
    }
}
```

BTW1: The second param in the exception constructor is for providing an embedded exception (e.g. in a catch block you want embed the caught exception into a new one). Providing a null is senseless.

BTW2: A certain degree of carefulness in writing code prevents a lot of headache situations ("Why the hell this is not working..."). In your pasted code several things are "smelling":

1. Delete unused code ("// TODO Auto-generated method stub")
2. Obey a perfect formatting (indents)
3. Follow the common usage of naming: variables and methods start with a lower letter, classes start with an uppercase letter. The name "List" already exists in java as name of a class (interface). AND: "list" does not say much. Here it would better be named "keys".

BTW3: It seems that you only set the key to delete to null. What is with the associated value (you're talking about "map")?